# How to Delete document on Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I understand that if I want to delete my document. I should get the postID value from Firestore so I can delete it.But I don't know how to get postID from Firestore . I hope it can help me.

[My Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcNR7.png)

CODE

```
PopupMenuButton<int>(
                    itemBuilder: (context) => [
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            value: 1,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      right: 8.0, left: 8.0),
                                  child: Icon(Icons.report),
                                ),
                                Text("delete")
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                    initialValue: 1,
                    onCanceled: () {
                      print("You have canceled the menu.");
                    },
                    onSelected: (value) {
                      Firestore.instance
                        .collection("thread")
                        .document()
                        .delete()
                        .then((_) {
                          print("success!");
                        });
                      },
                      
                ),
```

I want to press the popup to delete the document.

Comment: Are you fecthing all the documents, then showing the user to select which to delete?

Comment: please share the thread model you have made

Comment: I do like facebook that can press the popup menu and delete the posts that I have posted in the feed.